# How can I match a keyword and a filename with hash in perl?

Tags: perl, hashtable, keyword

I have a list of .txt files and a reference .csv file. My reference contains my keywords and I want to see if  a specific keywords can be found in the .txt filename I am going through in my foreach loop.

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %keyword;
my @files = glob("*.txt");
my $i     = 0;

foreach my $file (@files) {
  my %data_hash;

  open(INFILE, "$file") or die "Can't open file \n";
  while (<INFILE>) {
    my @data = split(/\t/, $_);
    $data_hash{ $data[0] } = $data [0];
    $keyword{$file} = $file;
  }
  close INFILE;

  open(REFERENCE, "$ARGV[0]") or die "Can't open file \n";
  while (<REFERENCE>) {
    my @all = split(/\t/, $_);
    if ($keyword{ "*$all[0]" }) {   #$all[0] contains the keyword
      print $data_hash{ $all[1] };   #print $data_hash when $all[1] eq $data[0]
    }
  }
  close REFERENCE;
}
```

My filename looks like `Hello_there_keyword.txt`. I know my $data_hash does contains the right value. Am I looking for the keyword in $data_hash{$file} when $file contains the keyword?

Comment: This code does not compile with `use strict`, because `%data_hash` is undeclared. Also, you have a syntax error where you forgot the `$`. You should not post code that does not compile. The error "odd number of elements.." comes from the statement `{data[0]}`, where the `{}` denote an anonymous hash, containing a single element.

Comment: Please show the code you are having problems with, as well as a sample of the data files. You are looking at only the first field on each line; is that correct?

Comment: @TLP the "my" and "$" do exist in my code.

Comment: @Borodin, I am looking for a match between any line of $all[0] and $file.

Comment: @Renaud That just makes it even stranger that you would post this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Odd number of elements in anonymous hash" is coming from this line:

```
$data_hash{ $data[0] } = { $data[0] };
```

- `{ ... }` is an anonymous hash (or a code block)
- `$data[0]` is a single element, thus an *odd* number.
- Thus `{ $data[0] }` is an odd number of elements in an anonymous hash.

  ```
  $data_hash{ $data[0] } = $data[0];
  ```

Would eliminate this error, but leave the defect that if you're just going to map something to itself, you can use an array and

```
print $data_hash{ $all[1] };
```

simply corresponds to

```
print $all[1];
```

- Also, a hint: list-assign works more meaningfully than assigning to an array and using "magic number slots". Thus,

  ```
  my ( $key, $data ) = split '\t'; # $_ is the default
  if ( $keyword{ $key } ) { 
      print $data, "\n";
  }
  ```

Comment: @Renaud, when you get a warning you don't understand it's good to insert `use diagnostics;` into your program.